# Screen switching using bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter. Before this, I only using page route but then I knwo this method is wrong. I want bottom navigation bar to be output like this.
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=2835ca041d187ee5247821a688712e63

But I don't know on how to implement it. I hope someone can help and explain to me.
And this is my code for what I have done so far.

```
class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBar({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NavBar> createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {


  int _isSelected = 0; 

  final List <bool> _animByPages = [false, false, false, false, false];
  List <bool> modifiedPages = [];

  final List<BottomNavItem> _listBottomNavItems =  [
    BottomNavItem(title:'Home', icon:Icons.home, page: HomeScreen()),
    BottomNavItem(title:'Activity', icon:Icons.receipt, page: ParkingScreen()),
    BottomNavItem(title:'Wallet', icon:Icons.credit_card, page: HomeScreen()),
    BottomNavItem(title:'Notification', icon:Icons.notifications, page: HomeScreen()),
    BottomNavItem(title:'Settings', icon:Icons.person, page: HomeScreen()),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: List.generate(_listBottomNavItems.length, 
            (index) { 
              return BottomNavItem(
              page: _listBottomNavItems[index].page,
              title: _listBottomNavItems[index].title, 
              icon: _listBottomNavItems[index].icon, 
              isSelected: _isSelected == index, 
              onTap: () {  
                setState(() {   
                  _isSelected = index;
                });
              },
              );
            }
            )
           );
  }
}

class BottomNavItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool? isSelected;
  final Function()? onTap;
  final Widget page;
  
  const BottomNavItem({required this.title,
                      required this.icon, 
                      required this.page,
                      this.isSelected, 
                      this.onTap
                      });
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
     onTap: () {
                onTap!();
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => page,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  width: 50,
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: isSelected == true ? Colors.black87: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
      
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Icon(icon, color: isSelected == true ? Colors.white: Colors.black87, size: 17),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                      Text(
                        title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 7,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: isSelected == true ? Colors.white: Colors.black87
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
              )
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: You already have an implementation on dartpad, What didn't you understand, Could you please be more specific ?

Answer (score 3):

So far this the most basic bottom navigation that I can provide.

```
class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNav> createState() => _BottomNavState();
}

class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: index,
        children: const [
          ScreenPageOne(),
          ScreenPageTwo(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int newindex) {
          setState(() {
            index = newindex;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: "Account",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1. The `int index = 0` is basically the value that will be the basis on which screen to display.
2. On the scaffold body I declared `IndexedStack` that has 2 screens, since the value of index is 0 the screen that would be displayed is `ScreenPageOne()`.
3. On the scaffold bottomNavigationBar the onTap function is the one responsible for changing the value of `index` to the new index value.

Comment: hi sir @keicredo , can u see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71933441/how-to-call-other-screen-using-dart-language

Answer (score 0):

Hey rider You can use this easy to understand and use.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'all_data_BestForYou/best_category_list.dart';
import 'bottom_tab_pages/chat_page_data/chat_page.dart';
import 'bottom_tab_pages/myprofile_page_data/myprofile_page.dart';
import 'bottom_tab_pages/saved_page_data/saved_page.dart';
import 'bottom_tab_pages/search_page_data/search_page.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<BestCaregoryList> favoriteList;

  Home(this.favoriteList);

static const routeName = '/Home';

 @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
  List<Map<String, Object>>? _pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
  _pages = [
    {'page': HomePage()},
    {'page': SearchPage()},
    {'page': SavedPage(widget.favoriteList)},
    {'page': ChatPage()},
    {'page': MyProfilePage()},
  ];
 super.initState();
}

void _selectPage(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedPageIndex = index;
  });
}

_bottomNavigationBarItem(Icon icon, Icon activeIcon, String label) {
  return BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: icon,
  activeIcon: activeIcon,
  label: label,
  );
}

Widget _createBottomNavigationBar() {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
    height: 80,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/bottom_tab_bar.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedIconTheme:
          IconThemeData(color: Color.fromRGBO(171, 178, 162, 1)),
      unselectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(171, 178, 162, 1),
      currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedFontSize: 11,
      unselectedFontSize: 11,
      onTap: _selectPage,
      items: [
        _bottomNavigationBarItem(
          Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          Icon(Icons.home),
          'Home',
        ),
        _bottomNavigationBarItem(
          Icon(Icons.search),
          Icon(Icons.search),
          'Search',
        ),
        _bottomNavigationBarItem(
          Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
          Icon(Icons.favorite),
          'Saved',
        ),
        _bottomNavigationBarItem(
          Icon(Icons.chat_outlined),
          Icon(Icons.chat_rounded),
          'Chat',
        ),
        _bottomNavigationBarItem(
          Icon(Icons.person_outline_sharp),
          Icon(Icons.person),
          'My Profile',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
    extendBody: true,
    bottomNavigationBar: _createBottomNavigationBar(),
    body: _pages![_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
  );
}
```

Comment: hi sir @meetpatel, can u see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71933441/how-to-call-other-screen-using-dart-language

Comment: @rider2501 for example, if you are making homePage then you should have to make different class file and call it from there like I have done in _pages.